# How to create a form choiceField with selection a models TextChoices?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a custom User Model with some TextChoices, How can I get that Selection "continents" into a Form?
so that i Render the html page with {{ form }} and the Choices appear?

I have tried both Forms1.py & Forms2.py None of them Work.

Models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser): #USER MODEL
    
    # CHOICES FOR USER CONTINENT
    class Continents(models.TextChoices):
        EUROPE = 'EUROPE' , 'EUROPE'
        AFRICA = 'AFRICA' , 'AFRICA'
        SOUTH_AMERICA = 'SOUTH AMERICA' , 'SOUTH AMERICA'
        NORTH_AMERICA = 'NORTH AMERICA' , 'NORTH AMERICA'
        OCEANIA = 'OCEANIA' , 'OCEANIA'
        ASIA = 'ASIA' , 'ASIA'
        
    username=None 

    nickname = models.CharField(max_length= 50, default = 'Not Set', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 500 , blank=True , null= True , default= "Not Set")

    email = models.EmailField(max_length= 256 , unique=True) #USERS EMAIL ADDRESS

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()
```

Forms1.py

```
class CompleteProfileForm(forms.Form):

    bio = forms.CharField(
        label='Bio: ',
        widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {
                'class':'bioInput'
            }
        )

    )
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['bio', 'continent']
        exclude = ['username']
        continents = forms.ChoiceField(label='Continents', choices= CustomUser.Continents)
```

Forms2.py

```
class CompleteProfileForm(forms.Form):

    bio = forms.CharField(
        label='Bio: ',
        widget = forms.Textarea(
            attrs = {
                'class':'bioInput'
            }
        )

    )
    continents = forms.ChoiceField(
         choices=CustomUser.Continents,
         widget = forms.Select(
             attrs = {
                'class':'continent',
                'selected':'Continent',
                'id':'continent',
            } 
      )
    )
```

I have also done this with the UserCreationForm and it is working this way, for field genders:

Forms.py

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    

    ......
    ......
    ......


    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2', 'gender']
        exclude = ['username']
        genders = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Gender: ', choices= CustomUser.Genders)
```

The error i Get is:
`TypeError: EnumType.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'`

Answer (score 0):

Django as a builtin `form.ChoiceField` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield)) that you found.
What you missed is the `choices=` argument takes a list a tuple representing choices. This list can be retrieved from a TextChoices via the `.choices` field ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices))

```
continents = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=CustomUser.Continents.choices,
)
```

The above should do the trick

Comment: Ok i'll try it thanks , do you maybe know why it worked when i extended UserCreationForm, and not when extending forms.Form?